# What is the meaning of negative second for a Morlet wavelet?

Tags: wavelet, transform, eeg

I kind of familiar with wavelet transform (I just used it in code but do not have a deep understanding about it). 
I've been reading an article and came across this sentence:

> where 4Fs is the length of the
>   Morlet wavelet with -2 to 2 second support with sampling frequency Fs

and I can't figure out what the -2 second means. By the way the article link is: [Deep Convolutional Neural Networks for Brain Computer Interface using Motor Imagery](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mpd37/theses/DeepEEG_IanWalker2015.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuous wavelets with symmetric envelope are often described, by convention, on a symmetric time interval: $[-T,T]$. The Gaussian being of infinite support, this means it is truncated.

This is only a matter of convention, as the wavelet shape is translated and dilated over the whole time axis. One could thus specify as well the same wavelet on the interval $[0,2T]$.